# What is the best c# wiki to integrate into an already existing website?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wiki, wiki-engine

We need to add a wiki to an already existing website, however we want only logged in users to be able to edit the wiki and we would prefer to use our own method of authentication.

Has anyone got any experiences with something similar or any suggestions of a good wiki engine for the job?

UPDATE:
Thanks everyone, the general seems to be consensus is that ScrewTurn is one of the best Wiki's, however does anyone have any experience of integrating it into your own website?

Imagine you have the website with the basic layout done and you have an authentication system already.

How can you bring the engine into the middle of that so that your layout and menus surround the wiki and it uses your own authentication system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a bit of evaluation of ASP.NET wikis recently, and the best one in my opinion is [ScrewTurn Wiki](https://stw.codeplex.com/).

You could try comparing some on [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org) if you want to see alternatives.

Comment: I have been adding Providers to the wiki and I think it will enable me to add it to the website seamlessly which is brilliant.

Comment: Could you please share the leftest recommendation because ScrewTurn is not supported any more, I came to know about the RoadKillWiki for .Net technology stack, what's your opinion?

Answer (score 4):

[Screwturn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/Wiki.ashx) is what Chuck Norris would use if he needed a Wiki

Comment: Possibly it 'rocks' because it appears to be one of the few remaining functional wikis on .net open source.  Unfortunately we are not as fortunate as our php brothers. (mediawiki, dokuwiki etc....)

Comment: It seems Screwturn have stopped supporting the development :( BUT- [roadkill.net](http://roadkill.codeplex.com/) support importing screwturns pages and is based on MVC for .NET4! Woohoo!

Answer (score 0):

I was pleasantly surprised at how good the Sharepoint wiki is (using Windows Sharepoint Services - WSS 3.0), though I dont know if this option would work for you. Worth looking at though... Sharepoint of course also supports custom authentication, strong authorization framework, etc.

UPDATE: To clarify, while I don't think that Sharepoint Wiki is the best of breed out there when it comes to wikis, my intent was that it integrates very nicely into the sharepoint model - and it is definitely "good enough".

Comment: You can't be serious.  I dispise the Sharepoint Wiki, one of Sharepoint's its weakest features IMHO.

Comment: Well, I admit I have yet to drink much "wiki koolaid", and I still think like sharepoint... However, as sharepoint's wiki blends wonderfully within the sharepoint framework, and sharepoint is so versatile - it fit my needs wonderfully. That said, I admit that its not the best choice for everyone...

Comment: The Sharepoint wiki is absolutely awful, it's the reason I was evaluating ASP.NET wikis in the first place - to find something actually usable for the developers at my company.

Comment: The only benefit to the Sharepoint wiki is that is lives in Sharepoint.

Comment: @Chris, well yes, thats kind of what I was saying - as I am Sharepoint centric, and was looking for something to integrate with that - it's exactly what I needed :).

Comment: Though I might consider looking at screwturn, for next time around...

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
Screwturn Wiki was once the best - it has become too clumsy and complicated.
it has lost its place as simple WIKI. i regret to have upgrade after Microsoft seem to have funded it.
I am currently looking to replace it with something else - it has become a beast.

Comment: Please update your comment if you find a good alternative.  Personally, I love ScrewTurn -- and I've evaluated plenty.  :)